# dropped column in pandas reappearing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a recarray after dropping a column. The original data has 33 columns and after dropping column 'a', I am left with 32 columns as expected. However, after calling to_records() on the dataframe, the original column has been reinserted with blank values. Is there a way to prevent this?

```
dat = pd.read_csv("testing.csv")
dat = dat.astype("float32")
dat.drop(['a'], axis=1, inplace=True)

temp = dat.to_records()

>>> dat.shape
(500,32)
>>> temp.shape
(500,33)
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this...

Answer (score 2):

You are dropping the column as expected but you have to assign the new data frame to your original data frame so it's overwritten.
So,

```
dat=dat.drop(['a'], axis=1, inplace=true)
```

That's it

Comment: You can test it: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5,3)), columns=list('abc')); df = df.drop('c', axis=1, inplace=True); print(df)` - Output: `None`;-)

Comment: That's still not working:
`>>> dat = dat.drop(['a'], axis=1, inplace=True)  
>>> type(dat)
<class 'NoneType'>`

dropping in place works, it's only when I try to convert it into a numpy array after dropping a column that there's a problem with the column getting restored.

Answer (score 1):

just do `dat.drop(['a'], axis=1, inplace=true)` instead of `dat=dat.drop(['a'], axis=1, inplace=true)`

When  inplace=True is passed, the data is renamed in place (it returns nothing), so you get a none type object in `dat`,

When inplace=False is passed (this is the default value, so isn't necessary), performs the operation and returns a copy of the object

[also see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893457/understanding-inplace-true)